# CloudFormation template to update service with new taskdef in ecs on fargate

Tags: service, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

i have a service running on ecs cluster using fargate as launchtype. I want to update the running service with new taskdefinition.

I have done this using UI but **i wanted to do this using Cloudformation** and can't find any documentaion related to this.

Updating an Running ECS Fargate service with a new task definition using a CloudFormation template.

Answer (score 2):

if your question is 'how to import existing resources into a Cloudformation Stack' then a recent feature of Cloudformation allows exactly that.

Cloudformation documentation about this feature is explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-new-stack.html). In short, you have to define a Cloudformation Template (JSON or YAML) that perfectly describes the resource that you want to import. Once the resources are correctly imported into the stack then you can proceed with stack updates that modify the resources (in your case the Task definition).

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/creating-resources-with-cloudformation.html) you can find some examples of ECS resources defined in a Cloudformation Stack Template.

If you are not familiar with Cloudformation Stack Templates, this procedure of importing resources might be kinda difficult; another viable option that I'd consider (and I would suggest you) is to create from scratch a Cloudformation Template of a Stack containing a new ECS Service with Task Definition and Cluster.

Comment: so as i require to update the service with new taskdefinition.
I used the update stack option and updated the image uri parameter and then this automatically updates whatever resources that are using image. So, in our case as we updated the image this updates the taskdef (this will create new revision to the existing taskdefinition) and udates the service with the new task def (will no create a new service).

This approch worked for me

Comment: great to hear that it worked! could you mark my answer as accepted to close this question ?! please and thank you

Answer (score 0):

With AWS CDK you can update existing service on ECS cluster looks like below (it may need to be update/correction):

```
// Define an existing ECS cluster
const existingCluster = ecs.Cluster.fromClusterAttributes(stack, 
    'ExistingCluster', {
      clusterName: 'your-existing-cluster-name',
      vpc: cdk.Vpc.fromLookup(stack, 'ExistingVPC', {
      vpcName: 'your-existing-vpc-name',
   }),
});


// Define an existing ECS service
const existingService = ecs.FargateService.fromFargateServiceAttributes(stack, 'ExistingService', {
  serviceName: 'your-existing-service-name',
  cluster: existingCluster,
});

// Define the new task definition you want to use
const newTaskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(stack, 'NewTaskDefinition', {
  memoryLimitMiB: 512,
  cpu: 256,
});

// Add container definition(s) to the new task definition
newTaskDefinition.addContainer('YourContainerName', {
  image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('your-container-image'),
  memoryLimitMiB: 256,
  cpu: 128,
  // ... other container configurations
});

existingService.taskDefinition = newTaskDefinition;
```